# Python 3.4 program generating substrings set from string does not gives correct output

Tags: python, output, substring

My code to give all k long substrings of a string (that is string[0:k],string[1:k+1], etc works OK on small test strings, but on long (100 and more) one string in output is missing. What could be a problem and how to fix it?  Here is a code (sure, Python):

```
def possible_kmers (a, b):
    kmers = []
    i=0
    while i<len(a)-b+1:
        kmer = a[i:i+b]
        kmers.append(kmer)
        i=i+1
    file = open("result.txt", "w")
    kmers.sort()
    for item in kmers:
        file.write(item+'\n')
    file.close()
```

Comment: could you give input and expected output to be more specify

Comment: if I give `possible_kmers("asdf",2)` I get `['as', 'df', 'sd']` is this correct or should it be `['as',  'sd']`

Comment: I am afraid expected output is not available anymore. (this was a course assignment)

Comment: Then what is your problem it is very unclear from your question should you get .Is the output of my previous comment correct

Comment: This is it. I want it to give output like  ['as','sd','df']. It crashes on really long input string.

Comment: you should use yield as the answer suggests :)

Comment: really long means  hundreds of characters

Comment: It _crashes_? What does that mean?

Comment: Vignesh Kalai, thank you very much for advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code would be missing a string on large inputs, but this code is cleaner, more encapsulated, and it works:

```
def possible_kmers(s, sublen):
    for i in range(len(s) - sublen + 1):
        yield s[i:i+sublen]


kmers = sorted(possible_kmers(SOME_S, SOME_SUBLEN))

with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for kmer in kmers:
        file.write('{}\n'.format(kmer)
```

Comment: You're welcome :). In that case, could you accept this so that the question will be marked as answered?